# How do I get content of log file (forever npm)

Tags: node.js, bash, forever

So i am running a nodejs server as a service with forever:

```
forever start server.js
```

I saw in the man that you can do something like this to get the log file content:

```
forever logs server.js
```

This doesn't work for me. When I run the command above it displays the help. Does anybody know how to do this? Maybe I started the server the wrong way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

type this command to find the location of the forever log files:

```
forever logs
```